# Find an overlapping X coordinate between 2 functions

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

just wondering if there is a theorem or method i'm not aware of to satisfy the following without iterating over X :

> Given 2 **RANDOM** functions on a graph, let's say :
> *y=sin(x)* and
> *y=sin(3.14159x/3)*
>
> Find any occurence of X where both functions share the same polarity. (*Polarity* means *Sign* in this context)

Please take note that the functions are completely random : it could as much be a simple **y=4**
as a complex **y=tanh(x/2.13454) + cos(1.938x) + sin(3.444) + ...**
However, they all share the origin [0,0].

Thanks !

Comment: What does *polarity* mean in this context? *Sign?*

Comment: Yup, exactly. I will update my question

Comment: How are the functions represented, and what is known about distribution?

Comment: Distribution is random, since functions are random. That's actually my main road block : I know the function definition (ex : y=sin(x/2.13454)), but the there is no guaranteed pattern in Y relative to X.

Comment: Multiply the two functions together and try to determine where the product is positive. This can be easy or hard depending on the functions, but it is a standard task when dealing with graphs of functions.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks man, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg Martin's answer is "Multiply the two functions together and try to determine where the product is positive. This can be easy or hard depending on the functions, but it is a standard task when dealing with graphs of functions."

Comment: This answer is taken, word-for-word, from a comment below your question.  It would be appropriate to cite that comment.

Comment: Totally agree. Is there a feature to link a comment to an answer or vice-versa ?

Comment: The point is you copied another's answer as your answer, and awarded yourself 15 points, Charles. Instead, request the commenter who answered  your question: Greg Martin, to post as an answer that so you can accept it.

Comment: @amWhy FYI, I agree with what you wrote in your comment, except note that an OP accepting their own answer doesn't give them any reputation points. For more details, see the network Meta's FAQ [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/562482)'s "Can I accept my own self-answer?" section where the first bullet point states "Accepting your own answer won't award you any reputation".

Comment: Thanks, @John for the reminder.  I had forgotten that fact!  Thanks again.